# Find all children who are not parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to retrieve all children who are not parent.

The table looks like this

```
ID  |  ParentID
---------------
1        NULL
2         1
3        NULL
4         2
```

At first I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp]
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ParentID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp])
```

but it returns no row.
I wanted to select all rows that are not in parentID. I don't understand why it's not working.

Then I tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] AS a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN 
(SELECT b.ID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] as b WHERE b.ParentID = a.ID)
```

but this returns all rows

Anyone can tell me what I'm missing

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `not in` exposes a well-known SQL quirk:

```
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ParentID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp])
```

To understand why, exand the query:

```
WHERE ID NOT IN (null, 1, null, 2)
```

And that translates to:

```
where id <> null and id <> 1 and id <> null and id <> 2
```

The trick is that `id <> null` is never true.  In SQL's [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), it evaluates to `unknown`.  And that means your where clause never approves any row.

To solve this, use `exists` (like Tim Schmelter's answer), or exclude `null` from the subquery:

```
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ParentID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID, ParentID 
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] t2
   WHERE t2.ParentID = t1.ID
)
```

This returns only rows where the `ID` is not the `ParentID` in another row. Hence this is not a parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp]
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ParentID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] WHERE ParentID  IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: ParentId is for the parent. So they can have a parent but has no child

Answer (score 1):

> why it's not working.

You are retrieving no rows from the first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp]
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ParentID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp])
```

Because of the `NULL` values in the `ParentID` there for the predicate becomes `UNKNOWN` therefore returns nothing, you can avoid this by using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ParentID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp])
```

Unlike all the other predicates in sQL `NOT EXISTS` works on two value logic `TRUE` and `FALSE` becuase there is are only two propabilities for the value either exists(ture) or false there is no way to return `UNKNOWN`.

There is also another workaround, that won't get what you are looking for in your case, which is, by eliminating these `NULL` values using `AND ParentID IS NOT NULL` but in your case won't get you the results you are looking for

Comment: `WHERE ID NOT EXISTS IN` ?  Don't think that's SQL ;)

Comment: I guess this is a typo: `WHERE ID NOT EXISTS **IN** (SELECT ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, `where id not exists` is not SQL either. You'll need a `where` clause in the subquery.

Comment: No worries, and downvotes are meant for "unhelpful" answers, where yours is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the IDs of the children (who are not Parents), you can also use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT ID
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp]

EXCEPT

SELECT ParentID
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Relace = on <>

```
SELECT *
FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] AS a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN 
(SELECT b.ID FROM [SMD].[dbo].[ProposalFollowUp] as b WHERE b.ParentID <> a.ID)
```